# I am not able to figure out how to carry out the Matrices multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have to carry out the following operation

R=[0,0.5,-0.25;-0.25,0,0.25;0,0,0.25];

B=[0,k21,k31;k12,0,k32;0,0,k];

G=inv(R).*B;

g=det(G);

but Matlab is showing the following error

??? Error using ==> horzcat

CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> g at 60
B=[0,k21,k31;k12,0,k32;0,0,k];

K21,K31,K12,K32 and k all have dimensions of 923334 by 1. Can anyone help me how can I carry out the following operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well for me. Check that the  k-values (k12,k31,k32...) are scalars (or 1x1 dimension)

**EDIT :**

For the case you mention, k's are nx1, one simple way is to perform a loop:

```
R=[0,0.5,-0.25;-0.25,0,0.25;0,0,0.25];

for ii=1:length(k)
     B=[0,k21(ii),k31(ii);k12(ii),0,k32(ii);0,0,k(ii)];
     G=inv(R).*B;
     g(ii)=det(G);
end
```

There is also a "vectorized" way to do that, but it seems to be good enough...

Comment: can you help me with another problem? well if in the G square(3X3) matrix, I just want to add the elements of only the first column, and not carry out the determinant. that is for ii=1:length(k) B=[0,k21(ii),k31(ii);k12(ii),0,k32(ii);0,0,k(ii)]; G=inv(R).*B; g(ii)=(summation of three elements of first row of G); end

Comment: (summation of three elements of first row of G) = sum(G(1,:))